# How do I check the type of a child inside a div?

Tags: jquery

I want to check the type of an element which is placed inside a div. I'm not able to reference the child element. I have tried using the following:

`$("#"+styleTarget).siblings(0).get(0)tagName`

Where `styleTarget` is a variable holding the `id` of the parent div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's difference between a child and a sibling. In the example below, all the `<li>` are childrens of `<ul>`. Each `<li>` is a sibling of all of the other `<li>` elements, because they are on the same level in the DOM tree.

```
<ul class="parent">
  <li>List 1</li>
  <li>List 2</li>
  <li>List 3</li>
</ul>
```

You should be using `.children()`, as documented here http://api.jquery.com/children/.

```
$("."+styleTarget).children().get(0).tagName
```

Comment: +1 For the really good explanation, beyond the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this:

```
var tagName = $("#"+styleTarget+" *")[0].tagName; //or...
var tagName = $("#"+styleTarget+" :first-child")[0].tagName;
```

The important part is the space between the selectors.

Comment: You don't need a space between the first-child filter.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - you do. Think about the difference between `li:first-child` and `ul :first-child`.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Yes, you do - your test is a bit flawed, here's your code, with the child *not* being a div: http://jsfiddle.net/nKTTB/ It alerts `DIV` because the *parent* is a `<div>` and it's a `:first-child` of body, but you're selecting the parent, not the child without a space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be looking at the `children()` function, unless you want to only look at a specific item, then, as GenericTypeTea suggested, use the [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) or [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selectors.

http://api.jquery.com/children/